# How does the Spanish Tax Agency view US S-Corporation income?

Tags: taxes, spain, freelance, tax-treaties

Given the following hypothetical situation:

1. I have an S-Corp in the US which generates 300K USD annually
2. I am a US citizen
3. I am an EU citizen and reside in Spain
4. I invoice the US S-Corp for 50K EUR per year (to live off of in Spain as a freelancer)
5. The remaining ~240K USD stays in the S-Corp's US bank account

How does the Spanish Tax Agency view this situation?

1. Would the S-Corp's total annual income need to be declared as personal income in Spain?
2. Would the ~240K USD that remained in the S-Corp be taxed at a US corporate tax rate?
3. Is only the invoiced income (the 50K EUR) considered personal income from the perspective of the Spanish Tax Agency? Or is the S-Corp's total income included?

I tried understanding the tax treaties between both nations but it was unclear to me how this situation should be classified.

Comment: If you haven't already, you might consider asking this on [Money.SE].

Comment: Good idea @phoog, I posted there: https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/130455/how-does-the-spanish-tax-agency-view-us-s-corporation-income. Thanks!